# Removing a tab from tabPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs4, tabpanel

```
var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('tabPanel');
for(var i=1; i<tabPanel.items.length; i++)
{
    tabPanel.items.removeAt(i);
    i--;
}
tabPanel.doLayout();
```

I'm trying to remove all the tabs (except the first one) from the tabPanel.
This code is doing that. I checked it using firebug.

But still, it is not reflecting in the UI.
Isn't doLayout() enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
tabPanel.items.removeAt(i);
```

Call

```
tabPanel.remove(tabPanel.items.getAt(i));
```

Then you're telling the container instead of the mixed collection to remove the tab

Another way to do it is

```
tabPanel.removeChildEls(function(tab){
  return tab != tabPanel.items.first();
});
```

Comment: it worked... thanks a lot... but can you tell me the why the above code wasn't working?

Comment: My comment in the answer explains it. `tabPanel.items.removeAt(i)` removes it from the items `MixedCollection` but doesn't notify the `tabPanel` that the tab was removed. The items collection should be accessed in a read-only manner. Use the `TabPanel` (inherited from `Container`) methods to add/remove child components (tabs)

Comment: I got it. But while adding and removing items from a normal Panel, it works. remove function automatically notifies the panel and does the layout. Then why not in tab panel?

Comment: @Shashwat You should not use it, it's not supported. Just because it works doesn't mean it's OK. There are methods in Ext.Container to add and remove items, why do you insist on hacking it?

Answer (score 0):

This closes a tab by clicking the middle button of your mouse.

```
var middleClick = $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 2){
              var tabPanel = <%= tabPanel.ClientID %>;    
              var activeTab = tabPanel.getActiveTab();
              if (e.target.textContent == activeTab.title) {
                  var activeTabIndex = tabPanel.items.findIndex('id', activeTab.id);
                  tabPanel.remove(activeTabIndex);
              }
          }
          return true;
    });
```

Hope it helps!! =)